# MongoDB query on multiple fields of object array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and I have a really complex requirement for which I am trying to write a query. Is there any way it's possible to write a mongodb query for this requirement?

**Sample Mongodb rows:**

```
Row1 --> {
    array1:[
            { type=“abc”, action=“taken”, points=10},
            { type=“abc”, action=“given”, points=20},
            { type=“xyz”, action=“given”, points=40},
            { type=“xyz”, action=“taken”, points=30}
        ]
     // other fields
}
```

```
Row2 --> {
    array1:[
            { type=“xyz”, action=“given”, points=50},
            { type=“xyz”, action=“taken”, points=40}
        ]
     // other fields
}
```

```
Row3 --> {
    array1:[
            { type=“abc”, action=“taken”, points=100},
            { type=“abc”, action=“given”, points=200},
            { type=“xyz”, action=“given”, points=500},
            { type=“xyz”, action=“taken”, points=400}
        ]
     // other fields
}
```

**Requirement:**

*Filter Conditions:*

Return the rows only if `type="abc"` *and* difference (points when `action="given"` - points when `action="taken"`) > 0

*Sorting:*

Rows need to be sorted in descending order of the difference between (points when `action="given"` and `type="xyz"`) and (points when `action="taken"` and `type="xyz"`)

*Expected output: :*

```
Row3 --> {
    array1:[
            { type=“abc”, action=“taken”, points=100},
            { type=“abc”, action=“given”, points=200},
            { type=“xyz”, action=“given”, points=500},
            { type=“xyz”, action=“taken”, points=400}
        ]
     // other fields
}
```

```
Row1 --> {
    array1:[
            { type=“abc”, action=“taken”, points=10},
            { type=“abc”, action=“given”, points=20},
            { type=“xyz”, action=“given”, points=40},
            { type=“xyz”, action=“taken”, points=30}
        ]
     // other fields
}
```

*Explanation of the output: :*
Row 2 will not come in the output because filter condition is not satisfied(It does not have any elements in the array with `type="abc"`)

Row 3 comes before row 1 in the response because of sorting condition(this difference value is greater in row3 than row 1 -->(points when `action="given"` and `type="xyz"`) and (points when `action="taken"` and `type="xyz"`))

Comment: Can you give some examples of possible expected results?

Comment: @Haruo Thanks for taking a look at my question. I have added expected output and explanation for that.

Comment: Now I can understand the rules about your problem. I will try to build a query that can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
(A working example at: https://mongoplayground.net/p/-rSHiqBwlEJ)
[Just click in 'run' button]

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    // 01) Filtering out documents that have type "abc"...
    $match: {"array1.type" : "abc" },
},
{
    // 02) Transforming every element of the array in one document...
    $unwind: "$array1",
},
{
    // 03) Summing the values by type ...
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        totalAbc: {
            $sum: { 
                $cond: { 
                    if: {$and:[{$eq: [ "$array1.action", "given"]},{$eq: [ "$array1.type", "abc"]}]},
                    then: "$array1.points",
                    else: {
                        if: {$and:[{$eq: [ "$array1.action", "taken"]},{$eq: [ "$array1.type", "abc"]}]},
                        then: {$multiply: ["$array1.points", -1]},
                        else: 0
                    } 
                } 
             }
        },
        totalXyz: {
            $sum: { 
                $cond: { 
                    if: {$and:[{$eq: [ "$array1.action", "given"]},{$eq: [ "$array1.type", "xyz"]}]},
                    then: "$array1.points",
                    else: {
                        if: {$and:[{$eq: [ "$array1.action", "taken"]},{$eq: [ "$array1.type", "xyz"]}]},
                        then: {$multiply: ["$array1.points", -1]},
                        else: 0
                    } 
                } 
             }
        },
    }
},
{
    // 04) Filtering the result where the total of type "abc" is greater than 0...
   $match: {"totalAbc": {$gt: 0} }
},
{
    // 05) Sorting the result by the total of type "xyz" ...
    $sort: { totalXyz : -1 }
}, 
{ 
    // 06) With id I retrieve all the original document information...
    $lookup: {
       from: "collection",
       localField: "_id",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "temp"
    }
},
{
    // 07) Designing the information in the same structure as the original documents ...
    $project: {"_id": "$temp._id", "array1": "$temp.array1"}
}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time and replying. What do we need to pass to this field in $lookup from: "collection" ? I am getting zero results even though there are many rows meeting the conditions

Comment: " collection"  is the name of your collection. In my case  at https://mongoplayground.net/p/-rSHiqBwlEJ the name of the collection must be "collection". In your case must be the name of your collection on your MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks @Haruo. Appreciate your help. I am testing the query and one thing I noticed is every field is coming as an array in the response as shown below. Is it possible to change it ? ``` "_id": [ ObjectId("5dbb1d0f9a17899b8ba690d6") ], "array1": [ [ ]] ```

Comment: Also looks like it is not subtracting the value when action="taken". It gives me the same value :(

Comment: This query is working fine after adding  $cond inside else part after  line number 35. However every field is still coming as an array. Trying to figure it out.